# dompdf/Laravel not respecting 'Roboto' font-weight

Tags: php, css, laravel, fonts, laravel-5.4

I've been looking for the error or the way to make dompdf work with my Google downloaded font, in this case "Roboto", and I don't know what else can I do to make this work, I've tried creating a link path to the `robot-font.css`, and tried pasting down all this code, inside a style tag in the PDF blade:

```
<style>
@font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Thin-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Thin-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Thin-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Thin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Thin-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
            font-weight: 100;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto-Thin';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Thin-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Thin-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Thin-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Thin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Thin-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
            font-weight: 100;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto-ThinItalic';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
            font-weight: 300;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto-Light';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-LightItalic-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-LightItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-LightItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-LightItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-LightItalic-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
            font-weight: 300;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto-LightItalic';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-LightItalic-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-LightItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-LightItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-LightItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-LightItalic-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
            font-weight: 400;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto-Regular';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Italic-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Italic-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
            font-weight: 400;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto-RegularItalic';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Italic-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Italic-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Medium-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Medium-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Medium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Medium-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
            font-weight: 500;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto-Medium';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Medium-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Medium-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Medium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Medium-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
            font-weight: 500;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto-MediumItalic';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
            font-weight: 700;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto-Bold';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
            font-weight: 700;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto-BoldItalic';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Black-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Black-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Black-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Black-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Black-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
            font-weight: 900;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto-Black';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Black-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Black-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Black-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Black-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-Black-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
            font-weight: 900;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Roboto-BlackItalic';
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic-webfont.eot');
            src:  url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../../../public/vendor/poncho/fonts/Roboto-BlackItalic-webfont.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
        }
</style>
```

And if I call a random `<p>` tag from the PDF as any of the font-family names and apply some weight or strong or bold tag it shows sans-serif with the proper weight, but not the Roboto.

Unfortunately the PDF font is very important for this project. Can't leave it as `sans-serif`.

Comment: Add `!important` to the end of the rules and they should override, that may fix it. If that doesn't work, you can use browser inspect element tools to find out if the elements are even loading the proper classes.

Comment: Didn't work.. I don't know what else can i try ..